# Get next 17 letters after keyword

Tags: php

I have this keyword: yt-lookup-title.
I want the next 17 letters after this in a variable. So I would have:

```
"<a href="/watch?v=HnlC81tWoY8"
```

How can I archive that I get it from all lines with this Keyword?
[Keywords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpc6d.png)

Comment: what do you want exactly ? which 17 letters ?

Comment: after the keyword https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpc6d.png

Comment: Can you explain what you would like to know ?

Comment: In the a text after a the word yt-lookup-title i want the next 17 letters in a single variable

Comment: @J.Doe do you mean you that you want to get the content of the `href` attribute?

Comment: @J.Doe which 17 letterss  from where to where ?????

Comment: that would not be a correct way to rely on class `yt-lookup-title` cause there could be multiple classes following `yt-lookup-title`

Comment: There is only this class with the link. @smarber yes :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `href` content, you can rely on [domdocument](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).
If I'm not mistaken, all the links (`<a>`) have this class `yt-uix-tile-link`. So you can do the following:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
// $html is a string containing the html of the page you're parsing
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

links = array ();
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a[@class="yt-uix-tile-link"]/@href');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $links [] = $node->nodeValue;
}

var_dump ($links);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is just great , thank you ! But I dont understand how I can use array further. I try:  echo $link[3]; But no output. But thanks again this works great! Just need them in a single $

Comment: Cool I try this later. I was doing it with ob_start(); and substr everything :C